# How do you start a workflow from another workflow - and pass an argument to the sub or child workflow?

Tags: google-workflows

This is a follow on question from [how do you start a workflow from another workflow and retrieve the return value of called workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209494/how-do-you-start-a-workflow-from-another-workflow-and-retrieve-the-return-value)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`workflows.executions.run`](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/workflowexecutions/v1/projects.locations.workflows.executions/run) helper method, which formats the request and blocks until the workflow execution has completed:

```yaml
- run_execution:
    try:
      call: googleapis.workflowexecutions.v1.projects.locations.workflows.executions.run
      args:
        workflow_id: ${workflow}
        location: ${location}   # Defaults to current location
        project_id: ${project}  # Defaults to current project
        argument: ${arguments}  # Arguments could be specified inline as a map instead.
      result: r1
    except:
      as: e
      steps: ... # handle a failed execution
```